# Overheating (fire thrown out of the nozzle)

Tags: fixed-wing, jet

0

At first I copied https://www.jetcat.de/en/productdetails/produkte/jetcat/produkte/hobby/Engines/P160_rxi_b

Where I manufactured and installed all the parts and they are very similar to the original product (also similar to the same quality of metal) I am facing two problems: The first: When the engine is running, the engine does not start properly (taking into account that the balance is not good because it contains vibration) and also makes a popping sound. enter image description here The second problem: Since the start of operation, the temperature begins to rise dramatically, which causes the turbine disc and the nozzle to redden, as it throws a large proportion of the fire outside the combustion chamber. Notes: The work circuit is manufactured and programmed manually by me: The kerosene pumping rate works with a continuous mechanism (I imitated the pumping algorithm in the main circuit) and I am not sure if I connected it correctly. After searching, I found that the fuel pumping algorithm should be used in particular, but I did not find sources to help me. Are there any suggestions to help me find solutions to my problems?

[image]